# How can I push to my GitHub account from AIDE

Tags: github, aide

I know I made it work some months ago, but I don't remember how.
I currently have no problem in pulling from public repos, but I can't seem to push.
Also I can't pull from private repos.
I have my id_rsa.pub in the .ssh directory and it's configured in settings. I'm 100% sure my rsa passphrase is right, as I tested it in git-bash.
I have AIDE Premium Key installed.

When I try to push it asks for User and Password and I'm not sure what to put there.

For user I've tried:
git@github.com
(my username)
(my mail I use for my commits)

For password I've tried:
(github account password)
(rsa passphrase)

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

First, m[ake sure your key is associated with your GitHub account](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection):

```
 ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

You should see a welcome message.

```
Hi USERNAME! 
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Second, don't forget you cannot clone/pull from private repository unless said private repositories are your own, or if you are a [collaborator](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository).

Similarly, you cannot push to a repository you don't own, or you are not a collaborator of.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My key is associated and I'm getting that same message. Also, I'm trying to push to my own repository. Do you know what should I use as Username and Password?

Comment: @Yuta73 If your key authenticate you correctly, you should not need any username/password. Check your remote URL used when pushing. It should be `git@github.com:me/myRepo` (replace `me` by your GitHub account name, and `myRepo` by your repository name)

Comment: That didn't work. Have you made it work using Android-IDE app? Because it works in my PC, but I'm trying to make it work in this specific app.

Comment: @Yuta73 I did not (and did not realize that AIDE was referencing Android-IDE). [I see it does support SSH URL though](https://www.android-ide.com/tutorial_git.html#section_create).